# Django generic UpdateView in Djangular

Tags: angularjs, django, django-forms, django-views, djangular

The Python source code for [Djangular Demos](http://djangular.aws.awesto.com/combined_validation/) gives examples of how to process the *post* request from a form that creates a Django object instance.  But they don't show how to process the *post* request from a form which updates an existing object instance.

The code for updating an object seems rather complicated: my code is missing something crucial.  Using my code I always get a form validation error: `Object with this Name already exists.`

I am using the Django generic UpdateView class and my model has a unique field called *name*.

My code:

```
from django.views.generic.edit import UpdateView

class MyForm(NgModelFormMixin, Bootstrap3FormMixin, NgModelForm):
    scope_prefix='form_data'
    form_name = 'my_form'
    class Meta:
        model = models.MyModel
        fields = ['name','person']

class MyModelUpdate(UpdateView):
    model = models.MyModel
    form_class = MyForm

    def post(self, request, **kwargs):
        if request.is_ajax():
            return self.ajax(request, **kwargs)
        return super(MyModelUpdate, self).post(request, **kwargs)

    # from the djangular combined_validation example
    def ajax(self, request, **kwargs):
        # tbd: need update-specific logic here: pass in instance
        # parameter (object) or set it from pk.  Base class post 
        # methods use self.get_object()
        form = self.form_class(data=json.loads(request.body))
        return JsonResponse({'errors': form.errors, 
                             'success_url': force_text(self.success_url)})
```

What code do I need to get Django to load the instance identified by the *pk* argument and attach it to the form.  That would be the default behavior when the request data comes from POST rather than ajax?

Answer (score 2):

After trial and error experimentation I came up with the following new implementation for the view's *ajax* method.  It passes my tests but feels clunky.

```
def ajax(self, request, **kwargs):
    form = self.form_class(data=json.loads(request.body), 
                           instance=self.get_object())
    try:
        form.save()
    except:
        # error is in form.errors
        pass
    return JsonResponse({'errors': form.errors, 
                         'success_url': force_text(self.success_url)})
```